# LocalDate to Date Conversion Problem in Hibernate: ORA-00932: inconsistent data types: should be: NUMBER received: BINARY

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am getting the error in an Hibernate project.There is a *Kisi* class. Here is the class structure of my project:

Kisi entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KISI" )
public class Kisi implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3283201458992402052L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ANAHTAR")   
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "kisi_Sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "kisi_Sequence", sequenceName = "KISI_SEQ" , allocationSize = 1)
private int anahtar;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade= {CascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinColumn(name = "UNVANANAHTAR", nullable = true)
private Unvan unvani;

@Column(name = "ADI", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(700 Byte)", nullable = false)
private String adi;

@Column(name = "SOYADI", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(1000 Byte)", nullable = false)
private String soyadi;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Kimlik kimligi;

@Column(nullable = true)
private LocalDate dogumTarihi;

@Enumerated
@Column(name="CINSIYET", columnDefinition = "smallint", nullable = true)     
private Cinsiyet cinsiyeti;

@Enumerated
@Column(name="MEDENIDURUMU", columnDefinition = "smallint", nullable = true)
private MedeniDurum medeniDurumu;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private KisiDetay kisiDetay;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "kisisi")
private Set<KisiIletisim> iletisimKumesi;

public Kisi() {
    
    super();
    String bosSozce = Sabit.BOSSOZCE;
    
    this.anahtar = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    this.unvani = null;
    this.adi = bosSozce;
    this.soyadi = bosSozce;
    this.kimligi = null;
    this.dogumTarihi = Sabit.BOSTARIH;
    this.cinsiyeti = Cinsiyet.VARSAYILAN;
    this.medeniDurumu = MedeniDurum.VARSAYILAN;     
    this.iletisimKumesi = new HashSet<KisiIletisim>(0);
    this.kisiDetay = null;
    
}   

// Constructors, getters and setters
```

EDIT-1
Andreas pointed out that the definition of enum is absent and not appropriate in the class. Kisi utilizes two enums, Cinsiyet (Gender) and MedeniDurum (Marital Status). Even though I changed it, problem still persists.

```
public enum Cinsiyet {

VARSAYILAN,
KADIN,
ERKEK
 
}



public enum MedeniDurum   {

VARSAYILAN,
EVLI,
BEKAR,  
DUL,

 
}
```

Database table structure is as below:

Database Table of *Kisi* entity:
[image: Database Table of Kisi entity]

When I try to insert *Kisi* , I am getting the error:

> Error : 932, Position : 121, Sql =insert into KISIPROFIL.KISI (ADI, CINSIYET, dogumTarihi, MEDENIDURUMU, SOYADI, UNVANANAHTAR, ANAHTAR) values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 , :7 ),
> Error Msg = ORA-00932: inconsistent data types: should be: NUMBER received: BINARY

original sql:

> insert into KISIPROFIL.KISI (ADI, CINSIYET, dogumTarihi, MEDENIDURUMU,
> SOYADI, UNVANANAHTAR, ANAHTAR) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

sql:

> insert into KISIPROFIL.KISI (ADI, CINSIYET, dogumTarihi, MEDENIDURUMU,
> SOYADI, UNVANANAHTAR, ANAHTAR) values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 , :5 , :6 ,
> :7 )

OracleErrorNumber:

> 932

stacktrace

> org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2886)org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3386)org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:8

How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Oracle Version:
Personal Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

References:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What is `Cinsiyet` and how did you expect that to be converted to a `NUMBER(5,0)` value? --- What is `MedeniDurum` and how did you expect that to be converted to a `NUMBER(5,0)` value? --- Since you don't have converters for those two types, the default is to serialize them to `byte[]`, hence the error message saying "received: BINARY", aka a byte array.

Comment: They are enums. I will edit post.

Comment: Then you should do a web search for e.g. [`JPA enum`](https://www.google.com/search?q=JPA+enum) or [`hibernate enum`](https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate+enum) to find articles that will *teach* you how to handle enums. You know, do a bit of **research**.

Comment: Actually, since error code mentioned about BINARY, I researched over KisiIletisim's boolean value. I haven't foresee that the error arise from the enum value.

Comment: **`BINARY`** is the name of the Oracle [**data type**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTSQL/types.htm#TTSQL148) used to store binary data. As the documentation says: *"The `BINARY` data type is a fixed-length binary value with a length of `n` **bytes**"*. It has nothing whatsoever to do with boolean values.

Comment: Even though I have changed code as per the handling of the enum in hibernate, problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been initiated from the "private LocalDate dogumTarihi;". The LocalDate cannot convert to DATE directly. As Thorben Janssen pointed out that "JPA will map it to a BLOB instead of a DATE or TIMESTAMP. That means the database is not aware of the date object and cannot apply any optimization for it. " https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

It has nothing to do with enum values. You should either

1- convert LocalDate to Date in class decleration. (dogumTarihi shall be "private Date dogumTarihi;")
2- You should write a converter.